# Python, calling a function with default value for arguments

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

In python, how can I call a function using the default value of an argument? I know it can be done just not passing the parameter when you call the function, but I would prefer to pass the variable through the function though. 
Having these two functions:

```
def A(argA1=defValA1, argA2=defValA2, argA3=defValA3):    
    argB1val=K*argA1
    argB2val=K*argA2
    argB3val=K*argA3
    B(argB1=argB1val, argB2=argB2val,argB3=argB3val)

def B(argB1=defValB1, argB2=defValB2, argB3=defValB3):
    print("First argument: "+argB1)
    print("Second argument: "+argB2)
    print("Third argument: "+argB3)
```

If I call A() with all the arguments, there’s no problem:

Main:

```
A(argA1val, argA2val, argA3val)
```

But what if I call A() with some missing arguments?:

Main:

```
A(argA1val)
```

In this case, inside the A() function

B() will be called taking the default values for the last two:

```
B(argB1= K*argA1, argB2= K* defValA2, argB3= K* defValA3)
```

However, I’d like to call B() using the default values of their last two arguments, something like :

```
B(argB1= K*argA1, argB2=defValB2, argB3=defValB3)
```

So, I would like A() to be something like:

def A(argA1=defValA1, argA2=defValA2, argA3=defValA3):

```
if (argA1==defValA1):
    argB1val=B.getDefaultValue("argB1")
else:
    argB1val=K*argA1

if (argA2==defValA2):
    argB2val=B.getDefaultValue("argB2")
else:
    argB2val=K*argA2

if (argA3==defValA3):
    argB3val=B.getDefaultValue("argB3")
else:
    argB3val=K*argA3

B(argB1=argB1val,argB2=argB2val,argB3=argB3val)
```

Otherwise, I’d need to do something like:

def A(argA1=defValA1, argA2=defValA2, argA3=defValA3):

```
if (argA1==defValA1 && argA2!=defValA2 && argA3!=defValA3):

    argB2val=K*argA2
    argB3val=K*argA3
    B(argB1= defValB1, argB2=argB2val,argB3=argB3val)

if (argA1!=defValA1 && argA2==defValA2 && argA3!=defValA3):

    argB1val=K*argA1
    argB3val=K*argA3
    B(argB1=argB1val, argB2= defValB2,argB3=argB3val)

if (argA1!=defValA1 && argA2!=defValA2 && argA3==defValA3):

    argB1val=K*argA1
    argB2val=K*argA2
    B(argB1= argB1val, argB2=argB2val,argB3= defValB1)

if (argA1==defValA1 && argA2==defValA2 && argA3!=defValA3):

    argB3val=K*argA3
    B(argB1= defValA1, argB2= defValA2,argB3=argB3val)

    ….
    ….
    ….

    Etc…
```

Having even a lot more combinations if we have more parameters.

Anyone knows if there’s a way to get the default value of a parameter to be passed in a function?

Thanks!

Comment: Your default values (`defValA1`, `defValA2`, `defValA3`) for the params of `A`, aren't appropriate enough to serve as default values, when you get to the part where you compute the args for invoking `B` from within `A`. A true default would be default in every sense. As suggested by @MatiasCicero, you might as well use some other values (such as `None`) as the defaults, in the place of `defValA1`, `defValA2`, and `defValA3`.

Answer (score 1):

Just let them be `None` and set them at execution time.

```py
def A(argA1=None, argA2=None, argA3=None):    
    argB1val= (K * argA1) if argA1 is not None else defValA1
    argB2val= (K * argA2) if argA2 is not None else defValA2
    argB3val= (K * argA3) if argA3 is not None else defValA3
    B(argB1=argB1val, argB2=argB2val, argB3=argB3val)

def B(argB1=defValB1, argB2=defValB2, argB3=defValB3):
    print("First argument: " + argB1)
    print("Second argument: " + argB2)
    print("Third argument: " + argB3)
```

Comment: Thanks Matias for your comment. Indeed, "None" would be an appropiate default value, but I don't think my question has been understood.

Comment: In the example you're showing, I'd like argB1val to take defValB1 if value argA1 is None...

Comment: argB1val= (K * argA1) if argA1 is not None **else defValB1**

Comment: But I don't know the value of defValB1 to implement it this way